# Samsung Galaxy S4 Old Emails Showing Up as New

Tags: email

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, which I switched to from a Blackberry in mid July 2013.  I continue to get emails that were dealt with when first received by either opening and reading, or opening and deleting, that show up again as new and unread.  My service provider (Rogers in Canada) tells me that it is because I have too many emails on the server.  I don't believe this as when I had a Blackberry this never happened.  They (Rogers) says this is because Samsung is a different OS.  Can anyone assist in how to deal with this?  I was told that Samsung is aware of this and on their next software update, this bug will be fixed.  Does anyone know if this is true?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the stock email client?

Comment: You might wish to check [Why does the email app on my Samsung Galaxy S4 keep loading old messages and telling me they're new?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49287/16575)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work on the S4, but it seemed to do the trick with my wife's S2, and my S3: change 'recent messages' (email account settings) from 25 (the default) to 'total'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Galaxy note client and webmail client showed they were read but s4 said I had 500+ unread. I went into my webmail client and selected all and forced it to mark all as read. A couple of seconds later all the messages on my phone showed as read and number went to zero.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, it was unbearable. i tried many other things but no solution. finally, i downloaded and installed "cloud magic" email app and it works very fine.